# Read Remote Changes to a Published Calendar before Publishing

Tags: ical

I have a calendar in Calendar.app which publishes to a server as an ics file. I can subscribe to this same calendar using the URL used to publish to it (both actions require authentication). However, this requires two separate calendars. What I want is to be able to publish to it and view any updates to it, as it might be changed from another client.

The current behavior is that any remote change to this ics is smothered by the next update from the local published calendar, which never checks the ics for changes before completely rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this is "working as intended", and switched to a CalDAV implementation, as it performs the functions I'm looking for.